# Display direction route on WKInterfaceMap in WatchKit

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

In one of my watchKit application I need to show the route between two locations on the WKInterfaceMap. I searched for different links including [Apple Developer Link](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/ui-elements/). But I didn't find any way to display the route on the WKInterfaceMap.
Then, how the **Uber** watchKit App displays the route on the WKInterfaceMap? Is it the Map or an WKInterfaceImage/UIImage?

Below is the screenshot for the **Uber** App.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they are be finding the route on the iOS app then passing it on to the watch in the form of a `WKInerfaceImage`

Answer (score 0):

WKInterfacemap is non interactive map. If you just want to give the user driving directions, use below code where you can specify destination lat and long and open Map application on iWatch. It will launch Map application on iPhone, from there WatchOS will receive routing information.

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( <ENTER DESTINATON LATITUDE>, <ENTER DESTINATON LONGITUDE>)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, add ressDictionary:nil))
mapItem.name = <DESTINATION NAME>
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
```